# Combining xml files with xmlstarlet returns blank file

Tags: xml, windows, xmlstarlet, command-line-tool

The code I am using is

```
xml sel -t -c ../NODTD/clean_apc200101.xml ../NODTD/clean_apc200102.xml > combined.xml
```

It seems to be executing, but the created file is empty. I feel like there's an easy fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I would also like to combine all the files in a directory dynamically but a file path of `../NODTD/*.xml` gets held up.

Comment: No. It's not that easy to combine two XML files. The safest way in your case would be using `xsltproc` with a simple template.

Comment: Your statement will copy (`-c`) the tag `../NODTD/clean_apc200101.xml` from the xml `../NODTD/clean_apc200102.xml`. So, yes, it is executing, and yes there will be an empty result.